# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors with ols()

Tags: r

`sessionInfo()`

```
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
## 
## Matrix products: default
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] compiler_3.6.2  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.6.2     htmltools_0.4.0
##  [5] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.3      stringi_1.4.5   rmarkdown_2.0  
##  [9] knitr_1.26      stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.11       digest_0.6.23  
## [13] rlang_0.4.2     evaluate_0.14

library(broom,pos=4,quietly=TRUE)
library(dplyr,pos=4,quietly=TRUE)
library(rms,pos=4,quietly=TRUE)

data(mtcars)
df <- within(mtcars, {
    vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
    am <- factor(am, labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
    cyl  <- ordered(cyl)
    gear <- ordered(gear)
    carb <- ordered(carb)
})
X <- names(df)
rsp <- 1 # response variable
Y <- X[rsp] # response variable (mpg)
Y1 <- paste(Y,"~",sep="")
X1 <- X[-rsp] # omit response variable, (mpg)
```

**The following chunk is from Stack Overflow (23jul2017) Logistic regression: how to try every combination of predictors in R?.**

```
n <- 3 # (all) n <- length(X1) 
out <- unlist(lapply(1:n,function(n) combn(X1,n,FUN=function(row) paste0(Y1,paste0(row,collapse="+")))))
mods = lapply(out,function(frml) lm(frml,data=df))
tmp = bind_rows(lapply(out,function(frml) {
    a = glance(lm(frml,data=df))
    a$frml = frml
    return(a)
}))

tmp$r.squared <- round(tmp$r.squared,4)
tmp$adj.r.squared <- round(tmp$adj.r.squared,4)
res2 <- with(tmp,data.frame(frml,r.squared,adj.r.squared,AIC,BIC))
OrdAIC <- res2[order(res2$AIC),]
OrdAIC[1,]

mod <- ols(mpg~wt+qsec+am,data=df,x=T,y=T)
```

**works**

```
mod <- ols(OrdAIC[1,1],data=df,x=T,y=T)
```

**produces Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
What am I doing wrong? 
How do I fix the code so that it works by reference rather then hard coding?**

Comment: Hey Peter, I am not sure what you are asking...where the error is coming up in your code. Maybe you could clarify a little bit. ALSO you say you are doing a logistic regression in the bold copy...but OLS is an ordinary least squares (linear) model...just wanted to point that out

Comment: The basic code is from Stock Overflow 23jul17 and dealt with logistic regression. I modified the code to work with linear regression, lm() in place of glm(). The error occurs when I use OrdAIC[1,1] in place of mpg~wt+qsec+am. An ols() object is then used to validate() the model. Later after defining equivalent models, delta AIC < 2, I want to validate the models with the validate() function to help with the selection of the best model. I get the same error with a vector of AICs or BICs.

Answer (score 0):

took me a while to understand your problem.

So before you use a function, see what is the required input:

```
?ols
Usage:

     ols(formula, data, weights, subset, na.action=na.delete, 
         method="qr", model=FALSE,
         x=FALSE, y=FALSE, se.fit=FALSE, linear.predictors=TRUE,
         penalty=0, penalty.matrix, tol=1e-7, sigma,
         var.penalty=c('simple','sandwich'), ...)

Arguments:

 formula: an S formula object, e.g.
          Y ~ rcs(x1,5)*lsp(x2,c(10,20))
```

So you need a formula object as input and your input is a factor:

```
class(OrdAIC[1,1])
[1] "factor"
```

For your step to work, do:

```
mod <- ols(as.formula(as.character(OrdAIC[1,1])),data=df,x=T,y=T)
```

Comment: StupidWolf, Thank you very much. It's just what I needed. PBM